# Immutable.js reference equality

Tags: immutable.js

given the following trivial code:

```
const Immutable = require('immutable');
const a = Immutable.fromJS({
    a: 1,
    b: [2, 3, 4],
    c: {
        d: 1
    }
});
const b = a.setIn(['c', 'd'], "Something else");
const c = b.setIn(['c', 'd'], 1);

console.log(a.equals(b)); // true
console.log(Immutable.is(a, c)); // true
console.log(a === c); // false?
```

And for the final comparison I'd expect it to return true since I'm setting the path `['c', 'd']` to something else and then back to the original value, and with structural sharing I would expect that it results in `c` holding a reference to the original data structure?

Do I mis-understand how this works?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First, this one `console.log(a.equals(b));` returns false actually:

Now for your question, as documented in Immutable.js [here](https://facebook.github.io/immutable-js/#equality-treats-collections-as-values) at "Return self on no-op optimization" sub-chapter:

> When possible, Immutable.js avoids creating new objects for updates
>   where no change in value occurred, to allow for efficient reference
>   equality checking to quickly determine if no change occurred.

There's that example:

```
const { Map } = require('immutable');
const originalMap = Map({ a: 1, b: 2, c: 3 });
const updatedMap = originalMap.set('b', 2);
updatedMap === originalMap; // No-op .set() returned the original reference.
```

> However updates which do result in a change will return a new
>   reference. Each of these operations occur independently, so two
>   similar updates will not return the same reference:

And that example:

```
const { Map } = require('immutable');
const originalMap = Map({ a: 1, b: 2, c: 3 });
const updatedMap = originalMap.set('b', 1000);
// New instance, leaving the original immutable.
updatedMap !== originalMap;
const anotherUpdatedMap = originalMap.set('b', 1000);
// Despite both the results of the same operation, each created a new reference.
anotherUpdatedMap !== updatedMap;
// However the two are value equal.
anotherUpdatedMap.equals(updatedMap);
```

Since you are changing the value, `setIn` returns a new reference. Therefore they are not equal by reference.

Hope I helped :)